# Microphone near view mirror

Tags: renault

I have brought a Renault Mégane convertible 58 plate, it has a small microphone near the drivers sun visor and rear view mirror. If I press the controls on the steering wheel it does come up with a mobile phone option, could the microphone be for phone connection?

I have gone through the manual and the stereo manual and have found nothing about the mic or being able to connect a phone...any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 3):

The microphone is almost certainly for the phone connection. The location near the sun visor is a common OEM installation point. That microphone might also be useful for voice commands, if your vehicle and / or head unit support them.

Regarding the connection to the phone, check the manual for instructions on Bluetooth devices. That's almost certainly the way they expect you to connect to your phone.

Comment: It could be an aftermarket hands-free as well, installers will often put the mic in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Owner Manual](https://www.renaulteurodrive.com.au/resources/handbooks/Megane%20Coupe%202016.pdf) I found online, it is the microphone for hand-free telephone use.

[image]

According to Renault's website, it looks like they have [two systems](http://gb.e-guide.renault.com/eng/Megane-hatch/Discover-multimedia-equipments); ***R-Link2*** and simply ***Radio CD Bluetooth***.

I looked in the [Radio CD Bluetooth handbook](http://world.e-guides.renault.com/sites/default/files/statics_pdfs/MUL/RadioCdBluetooth-NX1199_ENG.pdf) where it shows how to pair and unpair a telephone.

[image]

The RLink2 guide certainly has the same information if that is the system you have.

[image]

***NOTE: Images are for reference only. May not be identical to your vehicle.***